# How to define a "unique" constraint on a column of MySQL table in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unique, unique-constraint

I have a simple MySQL table with one column: `name`.

I would like to define a unique constraint on this column.

I can do:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :my_column_name
end
```

but it will work only at the application level, not at the database level.

What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not super-helpful, but it looks like there is not a great answer for enforcing uniqueness at the database level. From the [Rails migration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity):

> The Active Record way claims that intelligence belongs in your models, not in the database. As such, features such as triggers or foreign key constraints, which push some of that intelligence back into the database, are not heavily used.
>
> Validations such as validates_uniqueness_of are one way in which models can enforce data integrity.
>
> Although Active Record does not provide any tools for working directly with such features, **the execute method** can be used to execute arbitrary SQL.

It looks like running the SQL command yourself with the ActiveRecord execute method may be the best way to go if you really want to enforce uniqueness in the database.

Answer (score 34):

Add a unique constraint to the database itself using:

```
add_index :my_models, :my_column_name, unique: true
```

...through a migration (and you might want to make that my_column_name not accept any null values too:

```
class CreateMyModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_models do |t|
      t.string :my_column_name, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :my_models, :my_column_name, unique: true

  end
end
```

Comment: This answer is much better than others.  For unique constraint on multiple columns,  it can be like this `add_index :my_models, [:my_column_name1, :my_column_name2], unique: true`

Comment: How do you test this? As far as Rails is concerned, a not-yet-saved model that violates this constraint is still a valid model because it passes the model's application-layer constraints. It's a little messy to have to try to save it and then watch for a RecordNotUnique error from the database.

Comment: drewww: This is normally useful in situations where you have a factory method creating models and multiple threads of execution, where application-layer constraints could be fooled by the fact that record validations can depend on the presence of other records (example: unique usernames)

Comment: this is actually for Rails 4.  Question *does* state Rails 3, but this helped me :)

Comment: Thanks sircapsalot. AFAIK, this syntax has been the same since Rails 1.1.1 (http://apidock.com/rails/v1.1.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index). If you're referring to unique: true vs. :unique => true, That's actually a Ruby change back in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: It might be a good idea to create a constraint explicitly by using `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT` to document the intention. More on this at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/147/116880.