# if i add a uniqueness constraint to multiple columns do i also need to index the individual columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a table:

```
create_table :blobs do |t|
 t.belongs_to :user, index: true
 t.belongs_to :item, index: true
 ...etc...
end
```

But I have need for a database level uniqueness constraint on both `:user` and `:item`, should I *also* index the combined columns? Or would this be redundant?

`add_index :blobs, [:user_id, :item_id], unique: true`

Edit: this is not a duplicate question. This is about whether it is redundant to add mutlicolumn constraints when the individual columns themselves are also indexed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a "unique" constraint on a column of MySQL table in Ruby on Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405471/how-to-define-a-unique-constraint-on-a-column-of-mysql-table-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: They're not even remotely similar questions. The one you're linking is about *how to* define a uniqueness constraint, and mine is asking if it's redundant to add a constraint to the columns individually AND combined.

Comment: Worth looking into the fact it mentions that the Active Record way claims that intelligence belongs in your models, not in the database.

Comment: Also look at: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/validation-database-constraint-or-both

Comment: Thanks! But i'm confused. The first link says to define uniqueness in the model, while the second link says to define it in the database (which is what I'm doing). My question is whether or not it's useless to index the columns in both ways.

Comment: Worth a read as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098616/dos-and-donts-for-indexes

Comment: https://medium.com/@igorkhomenko/rails-make-sure-you-have-proper-db-indexes-for-your-models-unique-validations-ffd0364df26f

Comment: https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/05/09/faster-rails-is-your-database-properly-indexed.html