# activerecord unique constraint on multiple records

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, unique-constraint

how should I write the activerecord migration to reflect this :

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    c1 data_type,
    c2 data_type,
    c3 data_type,
    UNIQUE (c2, c3)
);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405471/how-to-define-a-unique-constraint-on-a-column-of-mysql-table-in-ruby-on-rails) adds a unique constraint on one column, but what I'm looking for is to create the unique constraint on the combination of 2 columns, like explained in the section [Creating a UNIQUE constraint on multiple columns](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-unique-constraint/).

**EDIT**

More precisely: I have a table account and a table balance_previous_month.

```
class CreateBalance < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change    
        create_table :balance_previous_month do |t|
        t.decimal :amount, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
        t.date :value_date
        t.belongs_to :account, foreign_key: true
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Since we're in January, the value date (i.e. balance at the end of the previous month) is `2020-12-31`.

I want to put a constraint on the table balance_previous_month where per `account_id`, there can be only one `value_date` with a given amount. The amount can be updated, but a given account can't have 2 identical value_dates.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=835afd20bed093ae1beee34e5f4edc5c

Comment: It's not my code, but an explanation on uniqueness on 2 columns. Comes from the link I added. My question is: how to translate that into an activerecord migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you added to the other post is not exactly equivalent to your request since one answer talks about enforcing uniqueness through the model while the other talks about using an index while in your example you are using a constraint. (Check [this](https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/uniqueness-in-postgresql-constraints-versus-indexes-4cf957a472fd) for more information on the difference between them).

There are 2 places where you can enforce uniqueness, application and database and it can be done in both places at the same time as well.

***Database***

So if you want to enforce uniqueness by **using an index** you can use this:

```
def change
  add_index :table, [:c2, :c3], unique: true
end
```

If you want to add a **constraint** as in your example you will have to run a direct sql query in your migration as there is no built-in way in rails to do that.

```
def up
  execute <<-SQL
    ALTER TABLE table
    ADD UNIQUE (c2, c3)
  SQL
end
```

Check the link above for more info about the difference between them.

***Application***

Enforcing **uniqueness through the model**:

```
validates :c2, uniqueness: { scope: :c3 }
```

Comment: You're right. My question wasn't clear. I'v updated it.

Comment: I wrote here a general answer using namings from your initial examples, but the ideas are the same though. Any of the methods above can provide what you want, and it's up to you which one(s) to use. I also updated a bit the answer to make the parts of the answer more distinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel Sindrestean, this code works :

```
class CreateBalance < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change    
        create_table :balance_previous_month do |t|
        t.decimal :amount, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
        t.date :value_date
        t.belongs_to :account, foreign_key: true
        t.timestamps
    end
    execute <<-SQL
        ALTER TABLE balance_previous_month
        ADD UNIQUE (account_id, value_date) # ActiveRecord creates account_id
    SQL
  end
end
```